# How to configure VBA to Work on all Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using this VBA to sort dates in ascending order. It works well on my first worksheet but i can't seem to get it to apply to additional worksheets. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160606
    On Error Resume Next
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Application.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Range("A3").Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                                        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

Comment: You may want to use the [`Workbook.SheetChange` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) instead.

Answer (score 0):

### One Code for All Worksheets

Use the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const Cols As Variant = 1 ' or "A"
    Const RangeAddr As String = "A3"
    Const Key1Addr As String = "A4"
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns(Cols)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    Sh.Range(RangeAddr).Sort Key1:=Sh.Range(Key1Addr), _
                             Order1:=xlAscending, _
                             Header:=xlYes, _
                             OrderCustom:=1, _
                             MatchCase:=False, _
                             Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    
    ' While developing, a simple error handler can clarify occurring issues.
'    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'        Debug.Print Err.Description
'    Else
'        Debug.Print "Sheet '" & Sh.Name & "' successfully sorted."
'    End If
    
    'On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```